# get source code of whole website - which loads additional content after scrolling down

Tags: javascript, wget

I want to fetch this site

https://www.film-fish.com/modern-mindless-action

to fetch the IMDB IDs of all movies listed there.
The problem is that the page loads all movies listed there just after scrolling down. So, a simple `wget` doesn't work.

Even if I scroll to the bottom of the page and view the source code, I do not see the last movie in the list (Hard Kill (2020)).

So the problem seems to be that the content is being created via JavaScript.

Has anybody a tip on how to achieve that?

Comment: you'll need some web scrapper or something - plenty of examples if you just search ... nasty thing, web scraping

Comment: I had good success with Selenium. See here if your browser and your programming language is supported: https://www.selenium.dev/ecosystem/

Answer (score 0):

> So the problem seems to be that the content is being created via a js
> script. Has anybody a tip on how to achieve that?

Indeed, executing JavaScript code is beyond scope of GNU Wget. You would need *browser automation tool*. If you know some Node.js or JavaScript I suggest taking look at PhantomJS [Quick Start](https://phantomjs.org/quick-start.html), [Page Automation](https://phantomjs.org/page-automation.html). Please take look at first example in 2nd link, you should be probably able to rework to your needs, i.e. instruct page to scroll down using JavaScript then extract what you need using JavaScript.

Comment: thank you, I'll take a look at PhantomJS